# Comparing Dates with Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-comparison

Moment.js is driving me nuts.

I have dates in this format 
10-Jul-2019 inside my array of objects `alldata` and here is my code: 
I need to filter out the objects where DueDate is outside of the range of last 90 days.

The issue is that the comparisons is not working properly...it's telling me that 
11-05-2019 > 08-08-2019

Am I missing something or is there a bug in moment.js? Feel free to suggest any method that does not use moment.js

```
 var todate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY"); 
        var fromdate = moment().subtract(90, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY");     
        var data = [];



        for (i = 0; i < alldata.length; i++) {
            duedate = moment(alldata[i].DueDate, "DD-MMM-YYYY").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
            if ( duedate >= fromdate) {
                alert("good!");
            } else
                alert("bad!");

        }
```

Comment: use `isAfter` method.

Comment: @deda thanks but it doesn't work ....still telling me that august 31 is before August 9th. Ugh

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Well yeah, compare two Unix formatted dates. They are just integers. `new Date().getTime()` // returns milliseconds passed from January 1, 1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing integers or numbers `format` returns a string.

Why not using the `isAfter` built-in method from moment.js library which compares two "moments".

```
    var fromdate = new moment().subtract(90, "days");   
    for (i = 0; i < alldata.length; i++) {
        let checkDate = new moment(alldata[i].DueDate,"DD-MMM-YYYY")
        let isAfter = checkDate.isAfter(fromdate);
        if ( isAfter ) {
            alert("good!");
        } else
            alert("bad!");

    }
```

Comment: see my code in the question: 21-Jul-2019 and my code actually converts already but the comparison still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings, because you're formatting the date before the compare.

This is a moment.js self-contained example:

```
//Include https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js
var oldDate = new moment('11-Jan-2018', 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
var newDate = new moment('01-Feb-2018', 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
if (newDate.isAfter(oldDate)) {
    alert('it works');
}
else {
    alert('no workie');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3yf5r60/4/

Use this snippet as an example for plain JS:

```
var now = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setMonth(yesterday.getMonth() - 1);
if (now > yesterday) {
    alert('it works');
}
else {
    alert('no workie');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lobpk519/

Comment: thank you! But the duedate I get from the database is a string...so do I need to break it into day month year and shove in the object then compare? I was hoping that in 2019 there would be a less hassle way...it seems that even with the fancy libraries dates are still a royal pain